# curl command works but C program fails NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Tags: ssl, openssl, libcurl, nss

there are a number of similar posts but I am trying to understand a little more than what those offer.
My curl commandline works fine and am able to talk to the server and get the data I want. The command looks like

```
curl -v --tlsv1.2 --cert ./service_cert.pem  --key ./service_private.key  "https://myserver"
```

But when I try to run my C program and examine the http client object I see this

```
errorBuffer = "NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
```

reading further I realized I have libcurl built with NSS which doesn't support reading cert from a flat file ( .pem)

How is then command line curl utility able to read the pem file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your client certificate into a NSS database, using `certutil`, and have your code use this database.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil